# How to get rid of conversion overheads?

Tags: c#

Take this example:

```
customer.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}! ", Console.ReadLine().ToString()));
```

(1) Why in C# we need to always put .ToString() to get it right?

(2) Convert.To...    Doesn't it creates overheads unnecessarily?

Further in the below given code: It gives error: "Input string was not in a correct format", after accepting user input.

```
    // Main begins program execution.
    public static void Main()
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        // Write to console/get input
        Console.Write("Enter customer's salary: ");
        customer.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}! ", Console.ReadLine().ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine("Salary in class variable is: {0}", customer.Salary.ToString()); 
        Console.Read();
    }

    class Customer
    {
        public Decimal Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

Here again, either I must use:

```
string sal =  Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}! ", Console.ReadLine().ToString()));
customer.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(sal);
```

Or, I must change the data type itself in the Customer class.

Can this overhead be avoided with anything in Generics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You do not need to call `.ToString()`.
2. Yes, it does.

You're trying to write

```
customer.Salary = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Your current code does the following:

- `Console.ReadLine()`: Reads a line from the console, returning a `String` object.
- `(...).ToString()` Returns the same `String` object
- `string.Format("{0}! ", (...))`: Returns a new `String` object containing the original string followed by `!`.
- `Convert.ToDecimal((...))`: Tries to parse that into a `Decimal` value.
  Since the string ends with `!`, it fails

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be happier if you use `Decimal.Parse` or `Decimal.TryParse` to do the conversions, rather than relying on `Convert.ToDecimal`.  You can write:

```
Decimal tempSal;
string sal = Console.ReadLine();
if (Decimal.TryParse(sal, out tempSal))
{
    customer.Salary = tempSal;
}
else
{
    // user entered bad data
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how internally Convert.ToDecimal and Decimal.Parse works?

Comment: In general, you should prefer 'Decimal.TryParse` because it attempts the conversion and returns `false` if the conversion was unsuccessful.  `Convert.ToDecimal`, on the other hand, throws an exception on error.  Especially in user interface code, it's much easier to handle a `false` return value than it is to handle exceptions.  Internally, I don't really know how the two differ.  I would suspect that when converting a string to a decimal, `Convert.ToDecimal` ends up calling `Decimal.Parse`.